# What anchor text should I use to my site's home page from guest posts I write for other sites?

Tags: links, backlinks, guest-blogging, anchor-text

What terms do I back link to my home page of my site in the publication of links guest post on big and valid sites?

Can we use our site brand as a keyword? For example, "google" word for address "www.google.com".

Comment: For effective SEO, use several keywords on different pages. Brand is one, but others would be common search terms for your company/website. On guest posts, your site would be appropriate.

Comment: How do I put different names for my homepage?  For example, what names do you have for Google homepage?

Comment: [Google has said](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/05/a-reminder-about-links-in-large-scale.html) that guest posts used to build links are against its webmaster guidelines when spammy links are included.   You could get your site penalized for guest posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor text isn't really a thing in 2018 so I wouldn't worry about it. The risk is you can over optimise.

As long as your homepage ranks for your brand (which it will as long as you don't over optimise by having loads of exact match anchor text) then you'll be fine.

Comment: For example, what names do you have for Google homepage?

Comment: Well If I were the owner of Google, I would want it to rank number 1 for the brand name, which is Google. That is what I mean.

Comment: So you chose the "Google" name for anchor text. it's true? So I have to choose my own brand name for anchor text.

Comment: You should make the anchor text contextually relevant to the content is it in. My point is don't get too hung up on anchor text.

Comment: relevant to the content? Even for homepage?

Comment: When you use anchor text, make it relevant to the keywords visitors would use to search for your site.  One of those would be your brand name.